# How can I interpolate a variable in a Ruby regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
 data.to_enum(:scan,/(#entity[0])/i).map do |m,|
        p $`.size
```

How can I use dynamic variable in regular expression?
`#entity[0]` returns a value, but in the above syntax #entity[0] is taken literally in the regex.

Answer (score 28):

You want `/#{entity[0]}/i`. `#{}` is the syntax for variable insertion in strings and regexes.