# How to mask all but last four characters in a string

Tags: ruby

I've been attempting a coding exercise to mask all but the last four digits or characters of any input.

I think my solution works but it seems a bit clumsy. Does anyone have ideas about how to refactor it?

Here's my code:

```
def mask(string)
  z = string.to_s.length

  if z <= 4
    return string
  elsif z > 4
    array = []
    string1 = string.to_s.chars

    string1[0..((z-1)-4)].each do |s|
      array << "#"
    end

    array << string1[(z-4)..(z-1)]

    puts array.join(", ").delete(", ").inspect     
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## positive lookahead

A [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) makes it pretty easy. If any character is followed by  at least 4 characters, it gets replaced :

```
"654321".gsub(/.(?=.{4})/,'#')
# "##4321"
```

Here's a description of the regex :

```
r = /
     .        # Just one character
     (?=      # which must be followed by
        .{4}  # 4 characters
     )        #
    /x        # free-spacing mode, allows comments inside regex
```

Note that the regex only matches one character at a time, even though it needs to check up to 5 characters for each match :

```
"654321".scan(r)
# => ["6", "5"]
```

`/(.)..../` wouldn't work, because it would consume 5 characters for each iteration :

```
"654321".scan(/(.)..../)
# => [["6"]]
"abcdefghij".scan(/(.)..../)
# => [["a"], ["f"]]
```

If you want to parametrize the length of the unmasked string, you can use [variable interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722145/how-can-i-interpolate-a-variable-in-a-ruby-regex) :

```
all_but = 4
/.(?=.{#{all_but}})/
# => /.(?=.{4})/
```

## Code

Packing it into a method, it becomes :

```
def mask(string, all_but = 4, char = '#')
  string.gsub(/.(?=.{#{all_but}})/, char)
end

p mask('testabcdef')
# '######cdef'
p mask('1234')
# '1234'
p mask('123')
# '123'
p mask('x')
# 'x'
```

You could also adapt it for sentences :

```
def mask(string, all_but = 4, char = '#')
  string.gsub(/\w(?=\w{#{all_but}})/, char)
end

p mask('It even works for multiple words')
# "It even #orks for ####iple #ords"
```

## Some notes about your code

### string.to_s

Naming things is very important in programming, especially in dynamic languages.

```
string.to_s
```

If `string` is indeed a string, there shouldn't be any reason to call `to_s`.

If `string` isn't a string, you should indeed call `to_s` before `gsub` but should also rename `string` to a better description :

```
object.to_s
array.to_s
whatever.to_s
```

### join

```
puts array.join(", ").delete(", ").inspect
```

What do you want to do exactly? You could probably just use `join` :

```
[1,2,[3,4]].join(", ").delete(", ")
# "1234"
[1,2,[3,4]].join
# "1234"
```

### delete

Note that `.delete(", ")` deletes every comma and every whitespace, in any order. It doesn't only delete `", "` substrings :

```
",a b,,,   cc".delete(', ')
# "abcc"
["1,2", "3,4"].join(', ').delete(', ')
# "1234"
```

Comment: While it works, I'd counter that it isn't as easily maintained as non-regex solutions.

Comment: @theTinMan: What would you maintain? It works fine and it's much shorter than any other solution. If it ain't broken, don't fix it ;)

Comment: @theTinMan: Also, you complimented an incorrect non-regex solution. It might have looked easy to maintain but wasn't.

Comment: I wish I had thought of that

Comment: What if `string` is a `Duck` that has a `to_s` method?

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a neat solution. I don't quite follow the syntax of this line: 

string.gsub(/.(?=.{#{all_but}})/, char)

How should one parse this?

Comment: @user211309: I updated the answer. It should be clearer now.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby makes this sort of thing pretty trivial:

```
class String
  def asteriskify(tail = 4, char = '#')
    if (length <= tail)
      self
    else
      char * (length - tail) + self[-tail, tail]
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can apply it like this:

```
"moo".asteriskify
# => "moo"
"testing".asteriskify
# => "###ting"
"password".asteriskify(5, '*')
# => "***sword"
```

Comment: Of course `char` should default to `'*'` since it is `asteriskify`.

Comment: `asteriskify_or_hashify_or_somethingify(tail, char)`

Comment: `any_char_acter_ify(tail, char)`

Comment: All good points. `hashificate` or `stomp` might also work here!

Comment: That's really neat, thanks. What is the reasoning behind putting 

self[-tail, tail]

? I don't quite get how to read that expression.

Comment: @user211309 That's how you capture the last *N* characters in a string. `"football"[-4,4]` is `"ball"`. It's `[position, length]` where negative positions are taken to mean "from end of string".

Comment: Absolutely. Don't be afraid to try things in `irb` as well, you can quickly find solutions by trying different operations or combinations of things without a whole lot of fuss. The Ruby core documentation is also worth at least skimming to get a taste for what's there as there's a ton of tools at your disposal, a much richer environment than most programming languages offer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
def mask(string)
  string[0..-5] = '#' * (string.length - 4)
  string
end

mask("12345678")
 => "####5678"
```

Comment: What does `mask('x')` do?

Comment: That explodes deliberately :D

Comment: What does `mask('xx')` do? What does `mask('xxx')` do? :)

Comment: Those too, obviously :P

Comment: That's very close to what I'd have used. Nice and simple.

Comment: `string[0..-5] = '#' * [(string.length - 4), 0].max` or `string[0..-5] = '#' * string[0..-5].length`. You still mutate the string, though.

Answer (score 2):

I will add my solution to this topic too :)

```
def mask(str)
  str.match(/(.*)(.{4})/)  
  '#' * ($1 || '').size + ($2 || str)  
end  

mask('abcdef') # => "##cdef"
mask('x') # => "x"
```

Comment: What does `mask('x')` do?

Comment: i like this answer. How about using gsub i.e. str.gsub(/(.*)(.{4})/, '#' * 4)

Answer (score 2):

I offer this solution mainly to remind readers that [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) without a block returns an enumerator.

```
def mask(str, nbr_unmasked, mask_char)
  str.gsub(/./).with_index { |s,i| i < str.size-nbr_unmasked ? mask_char : s }
end

mask("abcdef", 4, '#')
  #=> "##cdef" 
mask("abcdef", 99, '#')
  #=> "######"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tap`

```
def mask_string(str)
  str.tap { |p| p[0...-4] = '#' * (p[0...-4].length) } if str.length > 4
  str
end

mask_string('ABCDEF') # => ##CDEF
mask_string('AA') # => AA
mask_string('S') # => 'S'
```