# CodeCademy 4.6 bonus exercise

Tags: ruby

Hello guys i was tryng to do the bonus exercise 4.6

**"What could you do to make sure your redactor redacts a word regardless of whether it's upper case or lower case?"**

(link = https://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-mzrZ6/0/6?curriculum_id=5059f8619189a5000201fbcb)

This is my code

```
puts "Tell me the text to look for"
text = gets.chomp
puts "Tell me the word to censor"
word = gets.chomp

text_array = text.split(" ")

text_array.each do |parole|
if parole == ( word.downcase || word.capitalize )
puts "censure".upcase

else

 puts "#{parole}"
end
end
```

Why is it wrong? plz do not give me a total different code i would like to understand why mine is uncorrect, and how would be correct, thanks

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and the linked pages. When asking we need you to put in the effort to make your question readable. That includes properly formatting the content, which helps us help you. Not putting in that effort shows us you don't respect the effort we put in to help you. Also, SO isn't a discussion list or a Tweet. Use proper grammar. "plz do not..."?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) here with some regex:

```
#file.rb
puts ">> text?"
text = gets.chomp

puts ">> censor?"
word = gets.chomp

puts text.gsub(/\b#{word}\b/i,'*****')
```

running:

```
$ ruby file.rb
>> text?
#this is some MI5 text by mI5.
>> censor?
#MI5
#this is some ***** text by *****.
```

---

Q&As I used to help me with this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6722160/5101493
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/150115/5101493

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing here is that you're misunderstanding how the `||` or operator is used.

`if parole == ( word.downcase || word.capitalize )` isn't a way to check if `parole` is either equal to `word.downcase` *or* equal to `word.capitalize`. `||` is an operator that says an overall expression is considered true if either side of the `||` is true. So you need to write out both conditions in full e.g.

```
if parole == word.downcase || parole == word.capitalize
```

Also, it looks like you're misunderstanding `capitalize` vs. `upcase`. `capitalize` returns a string ensuring the first letter is a capital and the rest are lowercase, whereas `upcase` returns a string in all capitals.

So you could use:

```
if parole == word.downcase || parole == word.upcase
```

this would work as long as `parole` was entered in all caps or all lowercase.

Alternatively, you could ensure `parole` is in lower case:

```
parole = parole.downcase
```

and then just one condition would be needed:

```
if parole == word.downcase
```

As [sagarpandya82](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101493/sagarpandya82) mentioned there are other approaches using `gsub` etc. but the suggestions above are the closest in terms of fixing your original code.

Comment: @MarcoVanali if you found this answer useful consider accepting it by clicking on the grey tick so it turns green.

Comment: I have tried, but i can't because i don't have enough reputation. I'm sorry.